# master connection in ROS

Tags: ros, usb-cam-node, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Is it possible to run Master on system using network though wi-fi and connect remote computer which is in LAN to Master ROS.? Means Wifi to LAN communication (peer-to peer) is possible?
Problem Scenario:-
I am running usb_cam in master zbox using wi-fi, i want to connect master from remote computer connected to net using LAN, and i want to subscribe image_view of usb_cam.
As i know we are connecting ROS using IP. Does it matter for wifi and LAN different modem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198228/master-connection-in-ros/) by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-11-25

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As long as the LAN and wifi networks are fully connected it should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0